# Deploying NextJs + ExpressJs + postgreSQL (pgadmin)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, next.js, vercel

Here is the scenario:
I have NextJs app ready to go,
I have ExpressJs Server ready to go,
I have postgreSQL (pgAdmin) ready to go.

Can I or should I?

Deploy Next to Vercel, get a domain from GoDaddy (for example) and link it to project.
Deploy both express and database to heroku.

I don’t know if I can do all of them on Vercel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do stuff you need with Vercel.
Check this examples([express](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express), [mysql](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mysql)) of code, adapt it for your needs.

So, to deploy

1. Set up your project with ExpressJs NextJs and postgreSQL. (ofc using github repo for next steps). You can just `git clone` repository of express example, modify it git `push` to your github account.
2. All environment [variables you declare](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) in your `.env` folder !very important!, and checking your `.env` files are ignored by git (`.gitignore` file). This check is very important because you never expose .env files and connection string at git)
3. Once the local project works, you following step 4
4. You set up your vertical environment - linking [github repository](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#deploying-a-git-repository), setting up vercel settings you need. (for example, you can directly rent a domain name and set up it for production environment)
5. After, you are setting up [env variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) of vercel, with the same **variable name and values** (for example, your DB connection string, but NOT your base_url of course), you [deploy your project with vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/build-step).
6. Every time you git push your project, vercel will redeploy your online project and update all pages. It's really great.

What I suggest to you:

- you create very simple project with your needs(you mentionned) and
  try to deploy it.  In case of errors, you can google, it will not be
  so hard. Once a simple project works, you start to develop it.
- use mostly NextJS [hooks and code](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)  (not react), read the documentation. For example, instead of using `useEffect`(react) you use `useSWR`(react [lib created by vercel and nextjs teams](https://swr.vercel.app/)) hook for data fetching, so you will develop much more faster and "clean")
- try to use [Typescript](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#static-generation-and-server-side-rendering) if possible (but JS is also great)
- take your time and try to avoid pure react code (CTRL+C CTRL+V) from react projects.
- "fight" errors and check the console warnings from the beginning.
- if you like to have some video tutorials, you can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A63UxsQsEbU) (but it is js and not ts.)
- if you project will use multilanguage in future, s[et up all envirnoment](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#getting-started) and test it in the begginning. In this case also set up [i18n lib](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/i18n-routing) for future translations
- the hardest and important part is set up, test all your libs before you start "real" coding.

I am sure you will enjoy!

P.S. for the pgsql and express you will need to [construct your API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server),

Comment: Awesomeness  thank you very much. That is all i needed